# ActiveRecord::Store with default values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, store

Using the new ActiveRecord::Store for serialization, [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) give the following example implementation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :settings, accessors: [ :color, :homepage ]
end
```

Is it possible to declare attributes with default values, something akin to:

```
store :settings, accessors: { color: 'blue', homepage: 'rubyonrails.org' }
```

?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, there's no way to supply defaults inside the `store` call. The [`store` macro](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5daf07704ad21d885661216281ffc48b6ea6adfb/activerecord/lib/active_record/store.rb#L31) is quite simple:

```
def store(store_attribute, options = {})
  serialize store_attribute, Hash
  store_accessor(store_attribute, options[:accessors]) if options.has_key? :accessors
end
```

And all `store_accessor` does is iterate through the `:accessors` and create accessor and mutator methods for each one. If you try to use a Hash with `:accessors` you'll end up adding some things to your `store` that you didn't mean to.

If you want to supply defaults then you could use an `after_initialize` hook:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :settings, accessors: [ :color, :homepage ]
  after_initialize :initialize_defaults, :if => :new_record?
private
  def initialize_defaults
    self.color    = 'blue'            unless(color_changed?)
    self.homepage = 'rubyonrails.org' unless(homepage_changed?)
  end
end
```

Comment: +1, @mu usually in this scenario I use the `set if not set` idiom, i.e. `self.color ||= 'blue'; self.homepage ||= 'rubyonrails.org'`. This avoids the `dirty` checks..

Comment: @KandadaBoggu: The only downside to `||=` is if you have boolean attributes, using the dirtiness makes them all consistent. Shame there isn't a "set if not defined" like Perl's `//=`.

Comment: Yeh, that's true, one has to treat booleans differently if they use `||=` idiom.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to solve this too and ended up contributing to [Storext](https://github.com/G5/storext):

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Storext.model

  # You can define attributes on the :data hstore column like this:
  store_attributes :data do
    author String
    title String, default: "Great Voyage"
    available Boolean, default: true
    copies Integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use https://github.com/byroot/activerecord-typedstore gem. It allows you to set default value, use validation end other.

Answer (score 1):

The following code has advantage of the defaults not being saved on every user record which reduces database storage usage and makes it easy in case if you want to change the defaults

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  DEFAULT_SETTINGS = { color: 'blue', homepage: 'rubyonrails.org' }

  store :settings, accessors: DEFAULT_SETTINGS.keys

  DEFAULT_SETTINGS.each do |key,value|
    define_method(key) {
      settings[key] or value
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I just hacked together to solve this problem:

```
# migration
  def change
    add_column :my_objects, :settings, :text
  end

# app/models/concerns/settings_accessors_with_defaults.rb
module SettingsAccessorsWithDefaults
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    serialize :settings, Hash
    cattr_reader :default_settings
  end

  def settings
    self.class.default_settings.merge(self[:settings])
  end

  def restore_setting_to_default(key)
    self[:settings].delete key
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def load_default_settings(accessors_and_values)
      self.class_variable_set '@@default_settings', accessors_and_values

      self.default_settings.keys.each do |key|
        define_method("#{key}=") do |value|
          self[:settings][key.to_sym] = value
        end

        define_method(key) do
          self.settings[key.to_sym]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

# app/models/my_object.rb
  include SettingsAccessorsWithDefaults
  load_default_settings(
    attribute_1: 'default_value',
    attribute_2: 'default_value_2'
  )
  validates :attribute_1, presence: true


irb(main):004:0> MyObject.default_settings
=> {:attribute_1=>'default_value', :attribute_2=>'default_value_2'}
irb(main):005:0> m = MyObject.last
=> #<MyObject ..., settings: {}>
irb(main):005:0> m.settings
=> {:attribute_1=>'default_value', :attribute_2=>'default_value_2'}
irb(main):007:0> m.attribute_1 = 'foo'
=> "foo"
irb(main):008:0> m.settings
=> {:attribute_1=>"foo", :attribute_2=>'default_value_2'}
irb(main):009:0> m
=> #<MyObject ..., settings: {:attribute_1=>"foo"}>
```